# How to create a simple page like in picture

Tags: html, css

I am a bit rusty in HTML and CSS.
Can somebody suggest, how to create a line(in in the middle, and text on left and right?

[image: Center]

Ive tried one div with left: 50; second div right:50 and text align right

Comment: You can use any example of any flexbox tutorial. Just note that you can make a vertical bar with `border-right: solid 1px black`

Comment: Hey by the way you could also upvote an answer as well as accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flex container which I find cleaner, with a simple div that represents the vertical ruler you need.

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif
}
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.border {
  height: 1rem;
  border-right: 1px solid #8d8d8d;
}
.small {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span>500</span>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <span class="small">internal server error</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you wanted to position it.

If you're looking for absolute positioning you could so something like the following:

```
border-left: 1px solid black;
left: 35%;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
```

Make sure it's in a `position: relative;` container.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6mw9Lnay/

If you wanted a relative element:

You could define the height (and width) and apply the same principal with the border-left or border-right applied.

This way you can have elements side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
I created it like this and its almost the same:

```css
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.right {
  overflow:hidden;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-left: 1px rgb(46, 46, 46) solid;
  width:fit-content;
}
```